# Python Recursion Limit (infinite loop)

Tags: python, loops

asyncio&aiohttp webrequest while true loop

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Code working but after 4,5 minutes recursion limit error

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def main():
  async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as resp:
      async with resp.patch(f"https://mywebsite.com") as resp:
        if resp.status == 200:
          exit()
        else:
          print(f' > {resp.status} ')
          await main()


while True:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

How to disable recursion limit or how to make really infinite loop??

Comment: You can wrap your code in a `while True:` loop and get rid of the recursive call.

Comment: How to ? example pls @B Remmelzwaal

Comment: Add the `while True:` above the line `if resp.status == 200:` and remove `await main()`. That way, if the `else` is triggered the `while` block gets repeated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you're calling `main()` recursively within the `else` block. Instead of using recursion, you can simply use `while True` within the `main()` function to achieve an infinite loop. Here's a modified version of your code:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def main():
    while True:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.patch(f"https://mywebsite.com") as resp:
                if resp.status == 200:
                    exit()
                else:
                    print(f' > {resp.status} ')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

This way, the code will loop infinitely within the `main()` function without creating new function calls, avoiding the recursion limit issue and making the code easier to read.